# When I run "make project" in Intellij 14 for a scala project, where is the jar?

Tags: scala

Where does intellij store the jar file when I build a scala project?

I'm not using the assembly plugin, but even if I do there's no jar.

I'm trying to create a fat jar I can deploy to EMR to run a Spark job.

Comment: I'm not sure about Scala, but when you build a Java project with IDEA, it compiles each file, but does not create any jars. That is mavens job (in my case..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea will not create a Jar file if you merely build the project. You have to create an **artifact** and explicitly build the artifact.

Using the assembly plugin with SBT, you have to run `sbt assembly`, which will produce the fat jar under `target/scala-version/` (default location).